# ejecutar javascript en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

al acceder a una web via python existe alguna forma de mostrar el código de respuesta de un javascript? el que ve el usuario. Tengo esto:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

print(browser.open("https://www.web.com/"))

print(browser.get_current_page())

print(browser.get_url())
```

por ejemplo la repuesta de este .py es para ver el código fuente de la pagina pero no se ve el código de respuesta de javascript. Estoy buscando algo como cuando inspecciono el código, ahí se muestra el código de lo visual

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿lo que quieres es interectuar con los elementos del dom y ver que es lo que el sitio web responde?, o ¿sólo quieres tener el código js, cuando se carga la pagina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas un **headless browser**.

Para ello te aconsejo usar **Selenium Web Driver** y **PhantomJS**. 
De esta manera podrás hacer Web scraping de cualquier Web (incluso con javascript).
También inyectar código javascript, navegar, capturar imágenes, etc.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium
- http://phantomjs.org/

Para usarlo con python (en inglés de SO):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python

Un saludo.

Comment: Versiones recientes de chromium admiten la opción `--headless` y son una buena alternativa a PhantomJS.

Comment: Efectivamente. Puede ser una buena alternativa. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

De la documentación de [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup) (traducido, y la negrita es mía):

> MechanicalSoup automáticamente almacena y envía *cookies*, sigue redirecciones y puede seguir enlaces y enviar formularios. **No ejecuta JavaScript**.

Sin embargo recientemente ha aparedido una alternativa: [requests-html](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html), que se autodenomina "html para humanos". Específicamente diseñado para tareas de *Scraping* es incluso capaz de ejecutar el javascript y darte acceso al DOM resultante.

¿Cómo logra ejecutar javascript desde python si se trata de otro lenguaje? Pues "haciendo trampa". Realmente no se puede ejecutar javascript moderno si no es dentro de un navegador de verdad, pues emular el entorno de un navegador, con todas sus características, sería más complejo que lanzar uno. Lo que hace `requests-html` es utilizar la biblioteca [pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer) para lanzar Chromium con la opción `--headless` y "manejarlo por control remoto".

Chromium es una implementación de código de abierto de Chrome. La opción `--headless` hace que se ejecute sin abrir ventana alguna, pero por lo demás plenamente funcional (la "salida" de la página en cuestión se renderiza en una ventana "virtual" invisible, pero incluso podrías obtener una captura de pantalla del resultado).

Este tipo de técnicas suele usarse para *testing* de las aplicaciones web (para automatizar las acciones del usuario y ver que el resultado es el que se deseaba), pero `requests-html` lo usa más bien para obtener el DOM resultante que después puedes analizar para extraer enlaces y otras tareas de *scraping*.

Comment: No suelo entrar en esto, pero esta vez tengo genuína curiosidad ¿por qué el voto negativo?